# How to push manually to another repo once?

Tags: git, github

Some people talk about "URL's", some people talk about "remotes" and I couldn't find a simple and clear explanation for this.

Here's the idea:

- my client has his own git repo
- I have *my own* repo, and all my work is on it.

When I'm paid (or whatever), I would like to push manually to another repo once, and I would like that the client sees "clearly" only the pushes I've made for him (= like there are no other pushes/branches).

Here's my configuration:

```
$ git remote -v show
origin  git@github.com:olivierpons/my_repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:olivierpons/my_repo.git (push)
```

How to do this?

Comment: A *remote* is a short name for another Git repository. It mostly serves to store a *URL*. A [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (or [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)) is an Internet-style "phone number" by which you can have your Git dial up another Git. In your output above, `origin` is a *remote*, and the URL it stores is `git@github.com:olivierpons/my_repo.git` (which is a shortened, Git-specific spelling of `ssh://git@github.com/olivierpons/my_repo.git`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I would like that the client sees "clearly" only the pushes I've made for him (= like there are no other pushes/branches).

Then it is best to have:

- a separate local repository where you do only development for your client
- a separate GitHub repository, that your client can clone and inspect at will.

Trying to keep multiple works inside the same repository is not a good fit when you want to share only "a part of it" to an external collaborator.

If you really want to push one branch, as in [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60124823/6309), you need to make sure:

- it is an [orphan branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt) (no common history, or you would push the history of the previous branch it was created on)
- no merge was done to it (or you would push the history of the merged branch in addition of your own branch)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have network access to your client's repository. Then it is only a matter of pushing your changes (your branches, to be more precise) to your client's repository:

```
git push user@client_host:path/to/repository.git local_branch:remote_branch_name
```

If you do not have access to your client's repository, you can also go the route via an integration repository. A remote repository that both you and your client have access to. You then only push completed or paid work to that repository and your client pulls from there. The command to puplish your work is the same as above, only the url is different.

Having to type the full url every time becomes tiresome, that's where "remotes" come into play. A *remote* in Git is an alias for a remote repository url. You can easily add one and then use it instead of full urls:

```
git remote add client user@client_host:path/to/repository.git
git push client your_branch:remote_branch_name
```

Please note that pushing a branch will push the full history (including all commits) of this branch. This might or might not be a problem in your case.

Comment: If I dont precise `your_branch:remote_branch_name` does git try "default" branch = the branch I'm currently working on?

Comment: Small problem when I try your first solution..... "! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:path/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."

Comment: If the local and remote name of the branch are identical, you can simply do `git push remotename branchname`. If you do not specify it at all, behavior is dependent on the configuration value of `push.default`. The value `simple` (= push the current branch to a branch with the same name) became the default mode in Git 2.0. I prefer to always explicitly give the branches I want to push … makes the intent clear and avoids surprises.

Comment: `push` only allows you to add history to a remote, not to throw existing history away or change it. It looks like your remote repository contains different commits on branch master than your local repository. The error message is pretty clear and points to the correct documentation explaining what fast-forwarding is and why this is not possible in your current situation. You could of course just push your local master to a differently named branch on the remote: `git push remotename master:newname`